# lxml: How to parse xsi:nil="true"?

Tags: lxml

How can I make lxml insert some value when encountering `<value xsi:nil="true"/>`?

A snipped of the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<value>11</value>
<value>12</value>
<value xsi:nil="true"/>
<value>17</value>
```

My code:

```
value= doc.xpath('///value/node()')
```

Also tried:

```
value= doc.xpath('///value/text()')
```

Results:

```
value = ['11','12,'17']
```

What I want:

```
value = ['11','12,'null','17'] or some kind of placeholder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over `value` elements and get the `text`:

```
[elm.text for elm in doc.xpath('//value')]
```

Prints:

```
['11', '12', None, '17']
```